# Bicubic interpolation artifacts (image upscale)

Tags: c++, image-processing, interpolation, image-resizing, bicubic

I am using a bicubic interpolation algorithm in order to upscale an height map, and I am noticing some artifacts around the pixels boundaries.
However, these artifacts don't seem to appear when I use a simple cubic interpolation (spline).

Could it be because the bicubic interpolation doesn't guarantee the second derivative to be continuous, unlike the cubic spline ?
If so, is there known algorithms that have a continuous second derivative ?
Otherwise, is there a way to deal with these artifacts ?

Linear interpolation (shows the pixels boundaries):
[image: Linear interpolation]

Bicubic interpolation (artifacts visible at pixels boundaries):
[image: Bicubic interpolation]

Cubic interpolation (no noticeable artifacts):
[image]

I tried several bicubic formulas, which gave me the same results. Here are some examples:

- http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation
- http://www.paulinternet.nl/?page=bicubic

---

Edit:
I made some searches and found that B-Spline have a continuous C2 (also suggested by Bharat). I implemented it and it looks fine, even if it's an approximation and not an interpolation (it doesn't go through the samples).

B-spline (approximation):
[image: b-spline]

Comment: What software are you using to generate those images? Looks really nice!

Comment: I am working on my own OpenGL engine.

Comment: There's a bunch of related bicubic filters of which B-Spline is one. See http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~fussell/courses/cs384g/lectures/mitchell/Mitchell.pdf for the original paper and http://entropymine.com/imageworsener/bicubic/ for the simplified version. You might try the one recommended by Mitchell and Netravali with B=1/3, C=1/3.

Comment: @MarkRansom Nice paper. I implemented the generic function proposed there and tried several parameters. They all shows more or less artifacts (except b-spline). Mitchell is a good one though.

Answer (score 5):

second derivative of cubic B-Spline is continuous while that of bicubic interpolation is not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_interpolation

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485935/piecewise-interpolation-with-derivatives-that-is-also-twice-differentiable